# Angular POST 400 error

Tags: c#, angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, http-status-code-400

I am new to angular5 and I am getting this error when I try to add a new row of data to a table. ***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)***

I've tried the get and the post request. in my angular resource I have this code.
Customer is my DTO.

```
   newrow(nameRow: Customer): Observable<Customer[]> {
        return this._http.post(`${CONFIG.api_url}/newrow/${nameRow}`, JSON.stringify(nameRow))
            .map(res => super.mapResponse<Customer>(res))
            .catch(super.mapError);
    }
```

On the server side I am writing it like this.

```
  [Route("newrow/{nameRow}")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> NewRow(string nameRow)
        {
```

Comment: Make sure you are matching the parameters properly. nameRow is a Customer on the client side, and a string on the API.

Answer (score 0):

***Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request)*** which means your request is wrong.

If you are using a Http Post on client side, your service side code should look like

```
[Route("newrow/{nameRow}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> NewRow(string nameRow, [FromBody]string data)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're making it as a GET verb

base on your code

["newrow/{nameRow}"] is directly bind to the [string nameRow]

Change it to this

```
[Route("newrow/{nameRow}")]
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> NewRow(string nameRow, [FromBody]string data)
{ //where data is your payload
```